# Listing columns by two different criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Here is the query I am trying to execute: 
Repeat Question 13, but also include the price, and list the books in descending order by price. Within a group of books having the same price, further order the books by title.

Here is question 13:
List the book code and book title of each book that has the type SFI, MYS, or HOR. Use the IN operator in your command.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT BOOK_CODE, TITLE, PRICE
FROM BOOK
WHERE TYPE IN ('SFI', 'MYS', 'HOR')
ORDER BY PRICE DESC,
AND WHERE PRICE=PRICE
ORDER BY TITLE ASC;
```

Comment: Pratt and Adamski textbook? They have a lot of examples there including this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by `price` first, then by `title`.

Use this:

```
SELECT BOOK_CODE, TITLE, PRICE
FROM BOOK
WHERE TYPE IN ('SFI', 'MYS', 'HOR')
ORDER BY PRICE DESC, TITLE;
```

Comment: Thanks, however that did not order the books that are the same price by title for some reason..

Nvm, it did. Thanks so much, I know it was an easy question!

Comment: The title will be ordered for the same price